# Range slider control in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Windows phone 7 - how to implement range slider? Following URL is wpf Range slider example. I want to this in wp7 (http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx). i have tried the sample in wp7 application
But the XAML code is not working.

i am getting an error : The tag 'Track' does not exist in XAML namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not succeed make WP7Contrib RangeSlider work.
At one time found this [source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31216763/RangeSlider.zip), but it needed to be improved.
Also [Syncfusion Essential Studio for Windows Phone](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/controls) contains Range Slider and you can see [solution from Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-phone/features/slider/).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the Track class doesn't exist on WP.
[Track MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track.aspx)

I think you have to write your own Range slider control.

Maybe this will help you ;)
[Contrib](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/)
It says that they have a RangeSlider Control.

Answer (score 0):

All my hunt for a free range slider in WP was in vain. And finally resorted to creating my own control. Have posted in GitHub. Feel free to modify and use.

https://maythecodebewithyou.wordpress.com/2015/05/20/quest-for-a-range-control/

Thank you!